# Android studio Application keeps crashing as it launches

Tags: java

Im pretty new to android studio and java in general, I'm having this issue where the emulated application will crash while its launching and I'm not sure where the issue is. I think that its a runtime error but again I'm new and I'm not 100% sure

here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pink"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRestaurant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:maxHeight="150dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/resturant" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/txtTitle"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgRestaurant" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtBill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:hint="Bill Total"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtView" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnGuests"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:entries="@array/txtGuests"
        android:prompt="@string/guest"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtBill" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnTip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:entries="@array/txtTip"
        android:prompt="@string/tip"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnGuests" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/btnCost"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnTip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnCost" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.tipcalculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    double myBill = 0.0;
    double totalCost = 0.0;
    int numGuests = 0;
    double costPerGuest = 0.0;
    String groupTip = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        final EditText bill = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBill);
        final Spinner group = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnGuests);
        final Spinner tip = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnTip);
        Button cost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCost);

        cost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            final TextView result = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult));
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                groupTip = tip.getSelectedItem().toString();

                myBill = Double.parseDouble(bill.getText().toString());
                if(groupTip.equals("5%"))
                {
                    totalCost=myBill * 1.05;
                }
                else if (groupTip.equals("10%"))
                {
                    totalCost=myBill * 1.10;
                }
                else if (groupTip.equals("15%"))
                {
                    totalCost=myBill * 1.25;
                }
                else if (groupTip.equals("20%"))
                {
                    totalCost=myBill * 1.20;
                }
                else
                {
                    totalCost=myBill;
                }

                numGuests = Integer.parseInt(group.getSelectedItem().toString());
                costPerGuest = totalCost / numGuests;
                NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
                result.setText("Cost for each of " + numGuests + " guests: " + nf.format(costPerGuest));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do the logs say? You should be able to find which line is throwing an error.